# How to delete a node from a graph in scheme?

Tags: graph, scheme, racket

I have defined a graph that has the following structure
'(()()...)
The outer list is the graph itself, it contains nodes and edges.
The first inner list is a list of all of the nodes.
The following lists are the edges.  Edges are comprised of pairs of nodes.
So here is an example graph with 3 nodes, and 2 edges:
((n1 n2 n3) (n1 n2) (n1 n3))

I have been able to delete an edge like so:

```
(define (delete-edge edge)
    (if (member edge (edges))
        (build-graph (nodes) (remove edge (edges)))
        "ERROR no edge to remove"))
```

And this is build-graph

```
(define (build-graph nodes edges)
    (set! graph (append (list nodes) edges)))
```

but I am having trouble with deleting nodes.  If I delete a node, I also have to delete all edges related to it.  What I have so far is:

```
(define (delete-node node)
    (cond ((member (car (car graph)) (cdr graph))
           ("not implemented yet"))
        ("No Node to delete")))
```

I'm not sure what the next step is, after I've checked if the first node is contained in the lists of edges.  I know if it is contained, I need to go through and delete the lists that contain it.  Then I need to go to the next node in the node list and check that... But I'm not sure how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scheme you should prefer functional programming style solutions. In other words: it's not a good idea to mutate a global variable (`graph` in this case), it's better to receive the graph as parameter and return a new modified graph with the result. For example, this solves your problem:

```
(define (delete-node node graph)
  (cons (remove node (car graph))                  ; remove node from list of nodes
        (filter (lambda (e) (not (member node e))) ; delete edges that contain the node
                (cdr graph))))
```

The above uses list helper functions to implement the solution, which is the idiomatic way to write procedures. Notice that if we try to delete a non-existent node the same input graph will be returned, unmodified. Use it like this:

```
(define graph '((n1 n2 n3) (n1 n2) (n1 n3)))

(delete-node 'n2 graph)
=> '((n1 n3) (n1 n3))
(delete-node 'n5 graph)
=> '((n1 n2 n3) (n1 n2) (n1 n3))
```

If you definitely need to modify a `graph` global variable do it afterwards:

```
(set! graph (delete-node 'n2 graph))
```

Comment: Sorry, delete-node is a function designed within a function that uses dispatch.  I'm creating a graph object and implementing the methods contained within a graph - otherwise I would agree with you

Comment: But thank you for your help!  this is exactly what I've been looking for.  I've been going crazy over how to solve this